# full-width div on a fixed-width page

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed width centered page, and have to insert an full-width image in the middle of the page. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: code please or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/c59Pw/

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:500px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:purple;
    padding:30px;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Copy here.</p>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/500/300">
 </div>
```

Comment: and how to add fixed-width content after image?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `<img>` tag, inside your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

For full width according to the container or page size, you can simply use in CSS:

```
width: 100%;
```

For fixed size, enter in pixels or other units as follows:

```
width: 250px;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp