# I need a figure and image in a fixed width container to span the entire width of browser window

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

I'd like to solve this with CSS if possible, but if need be I can use a little jQuery.

In my pen (link below) I need to get the figure.image-x-large (and image content within) to span the entire full width of the browser window, even though it is within a 1230px container. I cannot modify the structure, but can add/take away classes where needed.

I saw a similar issue here *[full-width div on a fixed-width page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260322/full-width-div-on-a-fixed-width-page)*, but with that solution you cannot get the content below the image to flow properly. The content below the full width image in my pen needs to flow properly below it.

My HTML:

```
<article class="content">
  <h3>This is a headline</h3>
  <p>Across the centuries brain is the seed of intelligence, citizens of distant epochs, consciousness Apollonius of Perga billions upon billions Drake Equation network of wormholes another world Sea of Tranquility intelligent beings preserve and cherish
    that pale blue dot citizens of distant epochs globular star cluster network of wormholes another world? Vangelis Euclid hydrogen atoms tendrils of gossamer clouds quasar kindling the energy hidden in matter Cambrian explosion citizens of distant epochs
    dream of the mind's eye, a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam rings of Uranus Orion's sword made in the interiors of collapsing stars. How far away. Across the centuries intelligent beings.</p>
  <p>Corpus callosum courage of our questions how far away rogue circumnavigated hearts of the stars realm of the galaxies gathered by gravity cosmos, quasar extraplanetary. Of brilliant syntheses Drake Equation network of wormholes dispassionate extraterrestrial
    observer made in the interiors of collapsing stars dispassionate extraterrestrial observer hydrogen atoms culture astonishment another world paroxysm of global death dispassionate extraterrestrial observer prime number hundreds of thousands vanquish
    the impossible ship of the imagination. Descended from astronomers trillion descended from astronomers. Ship of the imagination encyclopaedia galactica, courage of our questions. Are creatures of the cosmos?</p>

  <figure class="image-x-large">
    <span class="img ">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/1250/750" class="" alt="" width="940" height="705">
    </span>

    <figcaption>
      <div class="caption">Franck Bacquet stands outside Ohm Force's first real office in 2006. The signage advertises French Fries and kebabs.</div>
      <div class="credit">&nbsp;Image: Ohm Force</div>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <p>At the edge of forever as a patch of light with pretty stories for which there's little good evidence rings of Uranus tesseract radio telescope of brilliant syntheses, made in the interiors of collapsing stars astonishment Cambrian explosion prime number.
    The ash of stellar alchemy take root and flourish bits of moving fluff, citizens of distant epochs consciousness as a patch of light how far away. Sea of Tranquility prime number inconspicuous motes of rock and gas rich in mystery a still more glorious
    dawn awaits galaxies great turbulent clouds citizens of distant epochs. Astonishment vanquish the impossible Hypatia.</p>
  <p>Hundreds of thousands radio telescope, courage of our questions shores of the cosmic ocean dream of the mind's eye, kindling the energy hidden in matter Euclid. The sky calls to us, a still more glorious dawn awaits! Light years. Descended from astronomers
    cosmic fugue, a billion trillion Flatland extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence gathered by gravity birth Sea of Tranquility, Vangelis two ghostly white figures in coveralls and helmets are soflty dancing, birth tesseract, tingling of
    the spine, ship of the imagination hydrogen atoms, not a sunrise but a galaxyrise cosmic fugue and billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon billions.</p>
  <p>The ash of stellar alchemy take root and flourish bits of moving fluff, citizens of distant epochs consciousness as a patch of light how far away. Sea of Tranquility prime number inconspicuous motes of rock and gas rich in mystery a still more glorious
    dawn awaits galaxies great turbulent clouds citizens of distant epochs. Astonishment vanquish the impossible Hypatia.</p>
</article>
```

My SCSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900);

body {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: snow;
}

.content {
    width: 1230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;

    .story-content-width {
        padding-left: 200px;
        padding-right: 200px;
        width: 830px;
        position: relative;
    }   

    h3, p {
        @extend .story-content-width;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: SteelBlue;
    }

    figure.image-x-large {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;

       .img {
           img {
                width:100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }

        figcaption {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid powderblue;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```

[My PEN](http://codepen.io/thommybrowne/pen/jbdWPE)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is actually pretty simple since there are units that handle the browser window.  The second part is a bit more difficult since you'll need to move the image to the edge of the window.  Since you have `position:relative;` on a parent of the image, it won't work with `position:absolute;`.  Instead try this:

```
figure.image-x-large {
    width:100vw;
    margin-left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

This'll work until the viewport hits the width of your container, then the image will shrink.  You'll have to put in a media query to stop that from happening.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1230px){
    figure.image-x-large{
        margin:0;
        transform:translate(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both parts make total sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably expect I do highly recommend you to restructure the HTML instead of trying to solve this by css (it's only possible with hacky css)

the hacky css I'm talking about is this:

```
figure{
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: calc( -0.5 * (100vw - 1230px) );
}
```

You will also have to handle smaller screens than 1230px with this method by adding a media query, but your current css doesn't scale to smaller screens yet anyway.

Comment: i expected it doesn't in some browsers, however in my chrome it does work, but your solution is better for sure

Comment: Yeah, probably should have been more specific as to where it doesn't work.  As soon as I realize it doesn't work in one place, I just file it under "don't use this" at all.  http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have now, this will work fine.

I ended the "article" element before the "figure" element and then I opened it again after.

```
</article>
  <figure class="image-x-large">
      ....
  </figure>
<article class="content">
```

CSS adjustments was to remove `.content` class from your "figure" class rules.

```
figure.image-x-large {
   ....
}
figure.image-x-large .img img {
   ....
}
figure.image-x-large figcaption {
   ....
}
```

Working sample

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900);
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: snow;
}

.content {
  width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
.content .story-content-width, .content h3, .content p {
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  width: 830px;
  position: relative;
}
.content h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: SteelBlue;
}
figure.image-x-large {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
figure.image-x-large .img img {
   /* position:absolute;
 left: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  /*   min-width: 1230px;*/
  height: auto;
}
figure.image-x-large figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid powderblue;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<article class="content">
  <h3>This is a headline</h3>
  <p>Across the centuries brain is the seed of intelligence, citizens of distant epochs, consciousness Apollonius of Perga billions upon billions Drake Equation network of wormholes another world Sea of Tranquility intelligent beings preserve and cherish
    that pale blue dot citizens of distant epochs globular star cluster network of wormholes another world? Vangelis Euclid hydrogen atoms tendrils of gossamer clouds quasar kindling the energy hidden in matter Cambrian explosion citizens of distant epochs
    dream of the mind's eye, a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam rings of Uranus Orion's sword made in the interiors of collapsing stars. How far away. Across the centuries intelligent beings.</p>
  <p>Corpus callosum courage of our questions how far away rogue circumnavigated hearts of the stars realm of the galaxies gathered by gravity cosmos, quasar extraplanetary. Of brilliant syntheses Drake Equation network of wormholes dispassionate extraterrestrial
    observer made in the interiors of collapsing stars dispassionate extraterrestrial observer hydrogen atoms culture astonishment another world paroxysm of global death dispassionate extraterrestrial observer prime number hundreds of thousands vanquish
    the impossible ship of the imagination. Descended from astronomers trillion descended from astronomers. Ship of the imagination encyclopaedia galactica, courage of our questions. Are creatures of the cosmos?</p>

</article>
  <figure class="image-x-large">
    <span class="img ">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/1250/750" class="" alt="">
    </span>

    <figcaption>
      <div class="caption">Franck Bacquet stands outside Ohm Force's first real office in 2006. The signage advertises French Fries and kebabs.</div>
      <div class="credit">&nbsp;Image: Ohm Force</div>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

<article class="content">
  <p>At the edge of forever as a patch of light with pretty stories for which there's little good evidence rings of Uranus tesseract radio telescope of brilliant syntheses, made in the interiors of collapsing stars astonishment Cambrian explosion prime number.
    The ash of stellar alchemy take root and flourish bits of moving fluff, citizens of distant epochs consciousness as a patch of light how far away. Sea of Tranquility prime number inconspicuous motes of rock and gas rich in mystery a still more glorious
    dawn awaits galaxies great turbulent clouds citizens of distant epochs. Astonishment vanquish the impossible Hypatia.</p>
  <p>Hundreds of thousands radio telescope, courage of our questions shores of the cosmic ocean dream of the mind's eye, kindling the energy hidden in matter Euclid. The sky calls to us, a still more glorious dawn awaits! Light years. Descended from astronomers
    cosmic fugue, a billion trillion Flatland extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence gathered by gravity birth Sea of Tranquility, Vangelis two ghostly white figures in coveralls and helmets are soflty dancing, birth tesseract, tingling of
    the spine, ship of the imagination hydrogen atoms, not a sunrise but a galaxyrise cosmic fugue and billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon billions.</p>
  <p>The ash of stellar alchemy take root and flourish bits of moving fluff, citizens of distant epochs consciousness as a patch of light how far away. Sea of Tranquility prime number inconspicuous motes of rock and gas rich in mystery a still more glorious
    dawn awaits galaxies great turbulent clouds citizens of distant epochs. Astonishment vanquish the impossible Hypatia.</p>
</article>
```